# In-App-Purchase item not longer active after app update

Tags: ios, keychain, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I have an App in the App Store which uses an In-App-Purchase item to unlock the full feature set. During all versions so far updates have never been a problem. The customers could download the new version from the App Store and the "full version item" which they did purchase before was still active: They could still use the full version after the update.

Today I have released a new version of the app and several customers are reporting problems with the full version: After the update the app only works as limited trial version. The app seems to have "forgotten" the information about the IAP.

I use MKStoreKit to handle the purchase and the information about the IAP is stored within the KeyChain. The users can restore the full version using the "restore previous purchase function" within the app which calls the corresponding StoreKit function.

How can it be that the information in the key chain is lost?

I do not know if all customers are affected by this problem or just some of them. All that I can tell is, that quite many reported the problem.

I have no idea what the problem might be.

This is the first version using iCloud and therefore it is the first time, that a entitlements file is included in the App. Could this be the source of the problem?

The "Keychain Access Groups" property in the entitlements file is set to "xy.mycompany.MyApp" which is the same as the bundle identifier.

I thought that without the entitlements the app used "xy.mycompany.MyApp" within the key chain to store the IAP information and that the information in the entitlements file is just to let different app share the same information in the key chain. Thus I am not sure if this might have to anything with the IAP problem.

What do you think? Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your entitlements file?

Comment: Encountered the same issue. also use MKStoreKit...

Comment: Andrei, did you figure out the root cause? Thanks.

Comment: Hi! No, I never found out what exactly caused the problem. I solved it by adding a good visible hint within the App Store description and the update notes. All further version since then did not had this problem any more. All new version now check if the App was full version before and if it is full version now. If wasFullversion != isFullversion the app displays a hint how to reactivate IAPs. Of course this is no real solution but it helped. I still belive that the entitlements have been the problem. But I cannot proof it..